# How to stop variables from resetting express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my app.js, I call a search function to an LDAP server, after that I am returned a cookie from the server for my next query. I try to store that cookie in my app.js file, as a app.local variable. But when I call the search again, for the next page. it will reset all my app.local variables to what they start as. Since it technically restarts my app.js file. What is a more permanent way to store variables, that I can control when to write and release the data.

Comment: Why does it technically restart your app.js file? It sounds like this shouldn't be required for your use-case. If you want something more permanent, use a DB.

Comment: So I am new to javascript, and especially to MEAN. I have certain times where I reset the value of that cookie to "", only if it hits an if clause. but I also have console logs to prove that I go into them. yet I don't, ever. So, the value gets reset to the start value, of "". I couldn't see any other reason it would reset the value, unless it restarted the app.js file/made a new instance.

Comment: Note that [`app.locals`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.locals) is global for the application. It isn't isolated to a single user or request, like cookies or a session can be. If the `app.locals` are modified in one request, that modification applies to all subsequent requests.

Comment: Wow, that's massive problem for me thanks @JonathanLonowski. Do I try to use res.locals, instead?

Comment: Sounds like you should consider using sessions: http://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/

Comment: I think the more appropriate question is "how do I achieve XYZ without having to restart the node instance". as it stands I'm seeing an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/167434)

Answer (score 1):

Try using session middleware.They are easy to use and store value till user doesnt logs out(or deletes cookies).

https://github.com/expressjs/session

You can find here how to use them in your app